# Mathematical relations of Gravitational waves and the Metric Tensor $T$

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, gravitational-waves

Ok so as we all know that Spacetime Curvature has Geometric Disturbances which are mathematically called Gravitational Waves. But the question I am asking is that why the Coordinative value of the Metric Tensor $T$ mathematically becomes 0 when a Gravitational Wave geometrically passes through that particular mathematical region of Spacetime?

Answer (score 0):

> why the Coordinative value of the Metric Tensor T mathematically becomes 0 when a Gravitational Wave geometrically passes through that particular mathematical region of Spacetime?

It doesn't.

By the way, $T$ is not usually the notation for the metric. Usually the metric is notated $g$, and $T$ is used for the stress-energy tensor.

Comment: Thanks for correction.